# Microsoft DNS set up with no forwarder

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, active-directory

On my Windows 2003 Server domain controllers, most of them don't have IPs entered for the forwarder 'All other DNS names'.  The only one that does, is one titled 'PDC'.

- So for DNS queries to the ones that
  don't have a forwarder for external
  domains, where do the requests go? 
  To that PDC server? or the root
  servers?
- Can I trace this with dig?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default if no forwarder is listed it will use the root hints addresses.

Comment: Is a forwarder with our ISP's dns better for any reason?

Comment: Yes, DNS lookups through your ISP's servers are usually faster; if those servers becomes unavailable, root hints will be used (by default).

Comment: If your ISP does stupid thing with DNS (Verizon and their idiotic wildcard response for invalid domain names to redirect to their own "search engine" site) you may not want to use their DNS servers.